# Shell script - new line after comma?

Tags: linux, shell, line, new-operator

I have a shell script I wrote that grabs a list of names from a location, and each name is separated by a comma , <-- I was wondering if there is anything I can write to make the list of names that gets stored in the text file to indent to a new line after each comma?

For example the list of names that gets stored in the text file look like this:

```
"Red", "Blue", "Green"
```

And I want them to look like this:

```
Red
Blue
Green
```

The data gets pulled from html code off a website so they have quotations and commas around them, if it's possible to at least format them to a new line, that would be great. Thanks if you help.

Answer (score 4):

Just use [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed).

```
% echo '"Red", "Blue", "Green"' | sed -e 's/\"//g' -e 's/, /\n/g'
Red
Blue
Green
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the comma separated date is in the variable $data, you can tell bash to split it by setting $IFS (the list separator variable) to ', ' and using a for loop:

```
TMPIFS=$IFS #Stores the original value to be reset later
IFS=', '

echo '' > new_file #Ensures the new file is empty, omit if the file already has contents

for item in $data; do
item=${item//'"'/} #Remove double quotes from entries, use item=${item//"'"/} to remove single quotes
echo "$item" >> new_file #Appends each item to the new file, automatically starts on a new line
done

IFS=$TMPIFS #Reset $IFS in case other programs rely on the default value
```

This will give you the output in the desired format, albeit with a leading blank line.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ print $i;}}'
```

Answer (score 1):

see below command line:

```
kent$  echo '"Red", "Blue", "Green"'|sed 's/, /\n/g'
"Red"
"Blue"
"Green"
```

Answer (score 0):

\n is for new line. Like "Red\n", "Blue\n", "Green\n"

Comment: Yes, but since I already have the data pulled from somewhere, is it possible to make something to look for each comma, and do a new line?

Comment: Yes, just search for each instance of a comma, and replace it with a \n

Comment: Yes but I want to look at the results in text editor without \n in there.